# DOWNLOAD MEDIA CONTENTS without using LWP module

Tags: perl, download, lwp

can v download media contents and save it in a destination folder without using LWP module??

Comment: What were your efforts?

Comment: Yes you can, why would you want to?

Comment: ive been trying a lot.. got a few codes but its related to cgi.. so was eager to know if i can make it simple somehow as dont know anything about cgi

Comment: i want to automate downloading certain files for my project..@MkV

Comment: can anyone tell me how to copy codes into comment?? it isnt accepting even after deleting characters to compress to the accepted length

Comment: not working!! @user1126070

Comment: You have given very little information. Please at least say what operating system you are using and explain why you want to avoid `LWP`. Are `HTTP::Client or `HTTP::Lite` acceptable alternatives?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience.. im new to perl and yes http::lite is something ive worked with.. i do want to paste the code here but i dont know y its not getting accepted!!!

Comment: You should edit your question and paste your code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing why you want to avoid `LWP` it is hard to help.

Coding an HTTP client is far from simple and a module of some sort or an external utility is pretty much essential.

I suggest [`HTTP::Client`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aClient), [`HTTP::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aLite) or [`HTTP::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aTiny), which are all stand-alone HTTP client modules that don't depend on `LWP`.

Comment: oh... ok.. i think ill search more on these modules.. maybe i missed something! thanx anyway.. @Borodin

Comment: *Please* explain why you don't want to use `LWP`.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, there are *many* ways of doing that. Neil Bowers made an excellent survey [CPAN modules for making HTTP requests](https://neilb.org/reviews/http-requesters.html); use it as a reference for your needs. In a nutshell:

[image: HTTP flowchart]
<sub>(source: [neilb.org](http://neilb.org/reviews/decision-tree.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could use commandline tools in linux to do this.

Check curl and wget documentation.

On windows you could install cygwin and use linux tools.

Regards,

Comment: Like Perl, both Wget and cURL will run happily on Windows if compiled appropriately: there is no need for Cygwin.

Comment: compiled appropriately, tats a lot for a newbie like me... will try though!! thanx!

Comment: Pre-built binaries of both are available for download.

Comment: http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.28.1

Comment: wget: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm